# How to implement MixedReality-ToolKit into an existing HoloLens project?

Tags: unity-game-engine, hololens, mrtk

I am extending the VideoCaptureExample for Hololens in Unity 2017.4.21f from this project: https://github.com/VulcanTechnologies/HoloLensCameraStream

Now I have to control the ScrollView and Buttons from my Canvas so I need the Gaze-Function from the MRTK. As soon as I try to implement the unitypackage from this page: https://github.com/Microsoft/MixedRealityToolkit-Unity/releases
for 2017.4.2.0 it shows me many C++ Exceptions while i didn't even use anything from that package:

```
Exception thrown at 0x76EDF2B2 (KernelBase.dll) in HoloLensVideoCaptureExample.exe: WinRT originate error - 0x80131534 : 'System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'WinRTBridge.WinRTBridge' threw an exception. ---> System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'WinRTBridge.TypeInformation' threw an exception. ---> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'GLTFSerializationUWP, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'. The system cannot find the file specified.
   at UnityEngineInternal.BootstrapHelpers.FillTypeMaps0(Dictionary`2 , List`1 )
   at UnityEng'.
Exception thrown at 0x76EDF2B2 (KernelBase.dll) in HoloLensVideoCaptureExample.exe: WinRT originate error - 0x80131534 : 'System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'WinRTBridge.WinRTBridge' threw an exception. ---> System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'WinRTBridge.TypeInformation' threw an exception. ---> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'GLTFSerializationUWP, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'. The system cannot find the file specified.
   at UnityEngineInternal.BootstrapHelpers.FillTypeMaps0(Dictionary`2 , List`1 )
   at UnityEng'.
Exception thrown at 0x76EDF2B2 in HoloLensVideoCaptureExample.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: Platform::COMException ^ at memory location 0x04EFE2F8. HRESULT:0x80131534 The text associated with this error code could not be found.
WinRT-Informationen: System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'WinRTBridge.WinRTBridge' threw an exception. ---> System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'WinRTBridge.TypeInformation' threw an exception. ---> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'GLTFSerializationUWP, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'. The system cannot find the file specified.
   at UnityEngineInternal.BootstrapHelpers.FillTypeMaps0(Dictionary`2 , List`1 )
   at UnityEng
```

I have already tried to check the Player Settings and took a research about it and I'm really stuck at this problem.
Here are my Player Settings from Unity:

[image]

Comment: Just to be sure: you already switched to Universal Windows Platform in the Build settings? Also what exactly is `the gaze function`? You mean a cursor and Pointer functionality such as PointerEnter, PointerDown etc?

Comment: The build without this toolkit already worked but it doesnt when im trying to implement MRTK (Mixed Reality ToolKit). Gaze is a part of the MRTK such as spatial mapping and other AR features. Furthermore, the build already worked when im not implementing the MRTK unitypackage

Answer (score 1):

I just took that version of MRTK and latest HoloLensCameraStream source. Running just the HoloLensCameraStream example produced some C++ TypeLoadExceptions; adding the MRTK 2017.4.2.0 didn't increase them nor did I see the GLTFSerializationUWP related typeload. 
On the contrary I did see in the output that GLTFSerializationUWP was loaded successfully, as it's now included in your project as part of including MRTK.

Two options:

- Generate a fresh UWP build from Unity into an empty folder
- Try updating to a newer MRTK that no longer has the reference to GLTFSerializationUWP.dll

Hope that helps!